# Get Data In Mapping From Another Contract

Tags: solidity

mapping(address => uint256) public something;

I would like to copy the data in the mapping above into a new mapping in a new contract. Kinda like exporting the data. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with an easy and clean way.

Comment: Any way to communicate with the data stored in it in an external way? Just interacting with the data at least. The mapping is public.

Comment: The problem is that a mapping is a deep complexe type. You can't return all the value of a mapping at once.

Comment: @Andromelus It is possible to return all values of mapping but since mapping can assimilate large amount of data, \the transaction may run out of gas if lot of data is being returned by mapping

Comment: Yes, sorry. What I meant was : "You can't return directly the mapping itself". You have to keep track of it size and loop trhough it, and as you said, yes, it can cost a lot. I think the best solution for this question is the one of hextet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no real way to natively iterate through a mapping in solidity so I'll propose a useful pattern

```
contract Test {
    address[] public addrs;
    mapping (address => uint256) public something;
    mapping (address => bool) public registered;
    function registerSomething(address _addr, uint256 _value) {
        require(!registered[_addr]);
        registered[_addr] = true;
        addrs.push(_addr);
        something[_addr] = _value;
    }
}
```

So using the above pattern everytime you register an address with a contract for the first time, it would be pushed onto the `addrs` array. You can then use this array to pull a list of ALL addresses who have an entry in your `something` mapping, query the mapping with your desired addresses returning the `uint256`.

Note due to block gas limit issues, I'd recommend against implementing the looping logic through your smart contract, and instead, implement it off-chain with a web3 script written in a language like JS or Python.

edit:

**Alternate Solution**

You could also use an event which is triggered when an address is registered with your `something` mapping, and then have a web3 script off-chain that listens to the events, and record the address locally.

Note that this solution has the disadvantage that during a hard fork, event logs are lost so I'd probably opt for the initial solution I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the mapping iterable and then use a function to get values of all the data stored in mapping. Below code creates two mappings, one to store the sequence number of account and another to store balance of account.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract oldContract{

  mapping(address => uint256) oldAccounts;
  mapping(uint256 => address) public accountSequence;
  //by default any new account will show false for registered mapping
  mapping(address => bool) registered;

  address[] listOfAddresses;
  uint256 public numberOfAccounts = 0;

  function registerAccount(address user) public {
    //only unregistered users will be registered
    require(!registered[user]);
    accountSequence[numberOfAccounts++] = user;
    listOfAddresses.push(user);
    registered[user] = true;
  }
}
```

- You can use the publicly available `numberOfAccounts` to find out how many addresses have been stored.
- The `accountSequence` function will be a getter function, which you can call from outside of blockchain, starting loop from `0` to `numberOfAccounts` and get all accounts that have been registered.